# Python: swapping numbers in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a following dataframe:

| position | number | account | status | new_account | new_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| top | 1 | acc1 | to_update |  |  |
| top | 2 | acc2 |  |  |  |
| top | 3 | acc3 |  |  |  |
| top | 4 | acc4 |  |  |  |
| top | 5 | acc5 |  |  |  |
| bottom | 6 | acc6 | to_update |  |  |
| bottom | 7 | acc7 |  |  |  |
| bottom | 8 | acc8 | to_update |  |  |
| center | 9 | acc9 |  |  |  |
| center | 10 | acc10 | to_update |  |  |
| center | 11 | acc11 |  |  |  |
| center | 12 | acc12 | to_update |  |  |
| center | 13 | acc13 | to_update |  |  |
| center | 14 | acc14 | to_update |  |  |
| center | 15 | acc15 | to_update |  |  |
| center | 16 | acc16 | to_update |  |  |
| center | 17 | acc17 | to_update |  |  |

positions_allowed = ['top','bottom']

expected output:

| position | number | account | status | new_account | new_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| top | 1 | acc1 | to_update | acc1 | to_update |
| top | 2 | acc2 |  | acc6 | to_update |
| top | 3 | acc3 |  | acc8 | to_update |
| top | 4 | acc4 |  | acc10 | to_update |
| top | 5 | acc5 |  | acc12 | to_update |
| bottom | 6 | acc6 | to_update | acc13 | to_update |
| bottom | 7 | acc7 |  | acc14 | to_update |
| bottom | 8 | acc8 | to_update | acc15 | to_update |
| center | 9 | acc9 |  | acc2 |  |
| center | 10 | acc10 | to_update | acc3 |  |
| center | 11 | acc11 |  | acc4 |  |
| center | 12 | acc12 | to_update | acc5 |  |
| center | 13 | acc13 | to_update | acc7 |  |
| center | 14 | acc14 | to_update | acc9 |  |
| center | 15 | acc15 | to_update | acc11 |  |
| center | 16 | acc16 | to_update |  |  |
| center | 17 | acc17 | to_update |  |  |

I want to re-arrange data based on above tables, so that items with "to_update" status are assigned to positions which are in "positions_allowed" array. If all available positions are used assignment should stop and following message should be displayed:

leftover: 2, numbers 16, 17

I tried various loops, but nothing seems to work. Any help is highly appreciated. My last code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Initial DataFrame
data = {
    'position': ['top'] * 5 + ['bottom'] * 3 + ['center'] * 8,
    'number': range(1, 17),
    'account': ['acc1', 'acc2', 'acc3', 'acc4', 'acc5', 'acc6', 'acc7', 'acc8', 'acc9', 'acc10', 'acc11', 'acc12', 'acc13', 'acc14', 'acc15', 'acc16'],
    'status': ['to_update', '', '', '', '', 'to_update', '', 'to_update', '', 'to_update', '', 'to_update', 'to_update', 'to_update', 'to_update', 'to_update'],
    'new_account': ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
    'new_status': ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

positions_allowed = ['top', 'bottom']

# Initialize variables to track leftover items and their numbers
leftover_items = []
leftover_numbers = []

# Function to update the DataFrame based on positions_allowed
def update_dataframe(group):
    global leftover_items, leftover_numbers
    # Filter to_update status within the group
    to_update_items = group[group['status'] == 'to_update']
    positions_in_group = positions_allowed[:len(to_update_items)]
    
    for idx, row in to_update_items.iterrows():
        position = positions_in_group.pop(0) if positions_in_group else None
        group.at[idx, 'new_account'] = row['account'] if position else ''
        group.at[idx, 'new_status'] = 'to_update' if position else ''
        
        if not position:
            # If no position is available, track the leftover items
            leftover_items.append(row['account'])
            leftover_numbers.append(row['number'])
    
    return group

# Group by 'position' and apply the update_dataframe function
df = df.groupby('position').apply(update_dataframe)

# Print the updated DataFrame
print(df)

# Print leftover items and their numbers
if leftover_items:
    print(f'Leftover numbers 2: {", ".join(map(str, leftover_numbers))}')
else:
    print('All items assigned successfully.')
```

Comment: The input has 16 rows, the output has 17 rows. If you're just swapping, how do you end up with more rows?

Comment: Please show what you tried. We'll help you fix it, we won't write it for you.

Comment: if you tried various loops then show them in question (not in comment). Maybe first you could filter rows with status `to_update` (to create one table) and rows with position `top, bottom` (tocreate second table) and later assign value from first table to second table - to create upper part of expected result. Similar you could do with rows without `to_update` and row `center` to create bottom part of expected result. And later you could join both parts to create expected result with all rows.

Comment: or maybe you should get columns `account` and `status` (to create new table), sort them using column `status`, and later assing this (sorted) table in place of columns `new_accoung`, `new_status`. I think both methods could be done without using `for-loops`

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```py
positions_allowed = ["top", "bottom"]

mask1 = df["status"].eq("to_update")
mask2 = df["position"].isin(positions_allowed)
c = mask2.sum()


def update_values(g, acc_iter, acc_iter2, cnt):
    for i in g.index:
        g.loc[i, "new_account"] = next(acc_iter2 if cnt[0] < 1 else acc_iter, "")
        cnt[0] -= 1
    return g


df["new_account"] = ""
df["new_status"] = df["new_status"] = ["to_update"] * min(len(mask1), c) + [""] * (len(df) - min(len(mask1), c))

df = df.groupby("position", group_keys=False, sort=False).apply(
    update_values,
    acc_iter=iter(df.loc[mask1, "account"]),
    acc_iter2=iter(df.loc[~mask1, "account"]),
    cnt=[c],
)

print(df)

print(
    "Leftover",
    (df["new_account"] == "").sum(),
    "Numbers",
    df.loc[df["new_account"] == "", "number"].values,
)
```

Prints:

```
   position  number account     status new_account new_status
0       top       1    acc1  to_update        acc1  to_update
1       top       2    acc2       None        acc6  to_update
2       top       3    acc3       None        acc8  to_update
3       top       4    acc4       None       acc10  to_update
4       top       5    acc5       None       acc12  to_update
5    bottom       6    acc6  to_update       acc13  to_update
6    bottom       7    acc7       None       acc14  to_update
7    bottom       8    acc8  to_update       acc15  to_update
8    center       9    acc9       None        acc2           
9    center      10   acc10  to_update        acc3           
10   center      11   acc11       None        acc4           
11   center      12   acc12  to_update        acc5           
12   center      13   acc13  to_update        acc7           
13   center      14   acc14  to_update        acc9           
14   center      15   acc15  to_update       acc11           
15   center      16   acc16  to_update                       
16   center      17   acc17  to_update                       

Leftover 2 Numbers [16 17]
```

Comment: It almost works :) It doesn't take into consideration "positions_allowed". If chnaged to:
positions_allowed = ["bottom", "center"] it still assigns items to top and bottom. I also tried with bigger dataframe and it doesn't work when position sets are not in consecutive order eg. "top" and "center"

Comment: @DearDeer Can you sort the dataframe before applying the script? You can then sort the dataframe back.

Comment: Works perfectly with sorting. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution :

```
positions_allowed = ['top','bottom']
to_update = df["status"].eq("to_update")
allowed = df["position"].isin(positions_allowed)

out = (
    df.assign(
        new_account=pd.concat([
        df.loc[to_update, "account"].iloc[:allowed.sum()],
        df.loc[~to_update, "account"]], ignore_index=True),
        new_status = np.where(allowed, "to_update", np.nan)
    )
)

left_numbers = out.loc[out["new_account"].isna(), "number"].tolist()
left_over = len(left_numbers)
```

Output :

```
print(f"{left_over=}, {left_numbers=}")

# left_over=2, left_numbers=[16, 17]
```

---

```
print(df.fillna(""))

   position  number account     status new_account new_status
0       top       1    acc1  to_update        acc1  to_update
1       top       2    acc2                   acc6  to_update
2       top       3    acc3                   acc8  to_update
3       top       4    acc4                  acc10  to_update
4       top       5    acc5                  acc12  to_update
5    bottom       6    acc6  to_update       acc13  to_update
6    bottom       7    acc7                  acc14  to_update
7    bottom       8    acc8  to_update       acc15  to_update
8    center       9    acc9                   acc2           
9    center      10   acc10  to_update        acc3           
10   center      11   acc11                   acc4           
11   center      12   acc12  to_update        acc5           
12   center      13   acc13  to_update        acc7           
13   center      14   acc14  to_update        acc9           
14   center      15   acc15  to_update       acc11           
15   center      16   acc16  to_update                       
16   center      17   acc17  to_update
```